# No overload for method matches delegate 'System.EventHandler

Tags: c#, gridview, merge, row, gridview-sorting

I am merging 2 rows in the column header of a Gridview.  The row has to sort.  To add the sorting ability to the column header I need to add the LinkButton control to the TableCell and then assign the Sorting method to the click event.  I am getting the 'No overload for SectionGridView_Sorting...'  I don't know how to add the event the the click action.  This is the code:

```
TableCell cellSecID = new TableHeaderCell();                 
cellSecID.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;                 
cellSecID.RowSpan = 2;
LinkButton lnkHeader = new LinkButton();
lnkHeader.PostBackUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.LocalPath;
lnkHeader.CommandArgument = "SectionID";
lnkHeader.Text = "SectionID";
lnkHeader.Click += new EventHandler(SectionGridView_Sorting); //This is the problem
cellSecID.Controls.Add(lnkHeader);
```

How to assign the Sorting method to the click event?

**UPDATE**
This is my Sorting Method:

```
 protected void SectionGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
             //Get the CourseID
            populateSectionGrid();
            DataTable dtSectionGridData = SectionGridView.DataSource as DataTable;
            SectionGridViewSortExpression = e.SortExpression;

            if (dtSectionGridData != null)
            {
                DataView dataView = new DataView(dtSectionGridData);
                dataView.Sort = SectionGridViewSortExpression + " " + ConvertSectionSortDirectionToSql(e.SortDirection);

                SectionGridView.DataSource = dataView;
                SectionGridView.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems you are binding with linkbutton click event with gridview_sorting event which already exists.

Comment: Your `SectionGridView_Sorting` implements `EventHandler` [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After UPDATE in the question there is workaround for your issue:

Change this line:

```
lnkHeader.Click += new EventHandler(lnkHeader_Click);
```

In the event handler:

```
void lnkHeader_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    sortExpression = "yoursortexpression"; //class level string or ViewState
    SectionGridView_Sorting(null, null); //intentionally calling gridview sorting event
}
```

In the gridview sorting event:

```
protected void SectionGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
         //Get the CourseID
        populateSectionGrid();
        DataTable dtSectionGridData = SectionGridView.DataSource as DataTable;

       string sDirection = "ASC" ;

        if(sortExpression == null)
        {   
           SectionGridViewSortExpression = e.SortExpression;
           sDirection = e.SortDirection;
        } 
        else
           SectionGridViewSortExpression = sortExpression

        if (dtSectionGridData != null)
        {
            DataView dataView = new DataView(dtSectionGridData);
            dataView.Sort = SectionGridViewSortExpression + " " + ConvertSectionSortDirectionToSql(sDirection);

            SectionGridView.DataSource = dataView;
            SectionGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE**: above code is not tested. Minor tweaks for refinements may be required. Like keeping `SortExpression` and `SortDirection` and checking in the `gridview sorting` event. in

Answer (score 2):

The signature of the event-handler method isn't compatible with the delegate type.

Presumably you are binding `LinkButton.Click` event with `GridView Sorting` Event.

```
 //section gridview should be like this
 protected void SectionGridView_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

However you need to bind with

```
void lnkHeader_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}
```

If you don't have existing `SectionGridView` sorting event then your `lnkHeader` Click event should look this: (Not good practice though)

```
void SectionGridView_Sorting(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

}
```

Comment: I have an existing SectionGridView sorting event which I added above.  I want to merge this row so that it spans 2 rows.  When I do that I lose the ability to sort on this column. I have to add the LinkButton to have the ability to sort.

Comment: I need the ability for this column to sort after I merge the 2 header rows.  I tried setting the SortExpression but that does not make it sortable.

Comment: I also tried this: ` lnkHeader.Click += new GridViewSortEventHandler (SectionGridView_Sorting);`  But that did not work either.

Comment: This will not work. You cannot bind gridview events to linkbutton.

Comment: How can I get this column to sort **after** I merge the row headers

Comment: Whatever you are doing in `SectionGridView_Sorting` make a method for that and call in both events. From linkbutton give your sort expression.

Comment: I use the GridViewEventArgs to get the SortExpression.  Can I cast the EventArgs to a GridViewEventArgs?

Comment: I need to get the SortExpression and SortDirection from the GridViewSortEventArgs.  I can't make a method that can be called in both.

Comment: When you select a column in GridView to be sortable, the Column Header becomes a LinkButton.  Is there another control that I can use to add the Sort event to be called?

Comment: see my second answer to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54152/discussion-between-hassan-nisar-and-gloria-santin).